# C Tic tac toe beginner

Tags: c, scanf

I'm getting a segmentation fault error — any suggestions? I'm trying to create a tic tac toe game, and I just started programming in C. Any suggestions would be helpful. I just want it to print to the terminal no graphics for now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Board[9];
    char row1[3];
    char row2[3];
    char row3[3];
    int j = 0;
    int turns = 0;
    char x;
    x = 'x';
    char o;
    o='o';
    int spot;
    printf("Hello, and welcome to Christian's Tic Tac Toe game\n");
    printf("Here's how it works: X goes first and chooses a place(1-9 corresponding to a place on the board)\n");
    printf("First to get 3 in a row wins. Have fun!\n");
    printf("X goes first where do you want to go?");
    scanf("%d", &spot);
    Board[spot-1] = 1;
    turns = 1;
    if (spot <=3)
    {
         row1[spot-1] = x;
         for (j =0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row1[j]);

         }
         for (j =0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row2[j]);

         }
         for (j=0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row3[j]);

         }
    }
    else if(spot >3 && spot <=6)
    {
         row2[spot - 4] = x;
         for (j =0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row1[j]);

         }
         for (j =0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row2[j]);

         }
         for (j=0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row3[j]);

         }
    }
    else
    {
         row3[spot - 7] = x;
         for (j =0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("\n%c", row1[j]);

         }
         for (j =0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row2[j]);

         }
         for (j=0; j<3; j++)
         {
             printf("%c", row3[j]);

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char x ="x";char o = "o";` is very wrong....

Comment: `printf("%s", row1[j]` is wrong too.

Comment: https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_22.htm

Comment: Too many issues. You need to get a good C book.

Comment: Compiler warnings are not for fun! Enable them, resolve them, then come back if you have a **specific** problem. This is no debugging service.

Comment: Why simple if you can make it complicated? - Any reason you don't use a 2D array?

Comment: yes olaf. I was not getting compiler warnings except for the two variables that are now fixed. If this type of post is not allowed i will remove it sorry.

Comment: @christian It is allowed, but don't expect a high rating for it. If you want you can delete it after you get the help you need (but then people answered your question won't get any reward for their effort), or let the community decide.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i will look into this further and then if i run into any REAL problems, i will make a better post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Johan Absolutely not.  This code is **broken**, please read what is on topic for Code Review before you recommend migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. The format specifier to print one character is `%c`, not `%s`.
- Your usage of `for` statement is wrong, so `j` will be too big and *undefined behavior* will be invoked by accessing out-of-range of an array.

Example of wrong code:

```
for (j<3; j++;)
{
    printf("%s", row1[j]);
}
```

Corrected code:

```
for (j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    printf("%c", row1[j]);
}
```

The same correction is required for loops using `row2` and `row3`.

---

More mistakes:

- `scanf("%s", &spot);` will invoke *undefined behavior*: wrong specifier is used again. `%d` should be used to read integers.
- `char x ="x";` and `char o = "o";` are bad because the values converted from the pointers converted from the string literals should be meaningless. You should use character constants instead like `char x ='x';` and `char o = 'o';`.
- Array indexes in C will begin with 0, not 1. `row1[3]` is not a valid object and you mustn't write something there when it is declared as `char row1[3];`. You should correct like

  - `row1[spot] = x;` -> `row1[spot - 1] = x;`
  - `row2[spot - 3] = x;` -> `row2[spot - 4] = x;`
  - `row3[spot - 6] = x;` -> `row3[spot - 7] = x;`
- Using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*. You have to initialized variables before using their values like `char row1[3] = "   ";`. Also initialize `row2` and `row3` like this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues. To start with

```
 scanf("%s", &spot);
```

is wrong, as `spot` is of type `int`. You should use `%d` for that. Otherwise, it  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that,

```
char x ="x";
char o = "o";
```

also looks wrong, you either want a `char` initializer (i.e., `'x'` and `'o'`), or you want to make the variables to pointer type and change the code accordingly.

Next, `Board[spot-1] = 1;` is probably wrong too, you're using an unbound index value `spot` to a bound value `9`. You should check the range of `spot` before using that as index value.

Also see the points mentioned by [MikeCAT in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38638407/2173917)

Comment: Yeah Thanks sorry for the stupid mistake

Comment: To clarify: only `Board[0]` to `Board[8]` are available. You cannot use `Board[9]` (strictly speaking, pointer `&Bound[9]` is valid, but you mustn't dereference it).

Comment: I updated the code, now im just getting gibberish printed to the terminal

Comment: @christian Using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.